# Slightly confused about the commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let's look at the group of all permutations of a set $\left\{ 1,2,3 \right\}$. There are exactly 6 elements in this group: $\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$, $\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   1 & 3 & 2  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$, $\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   2 & 1 & 3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$, $\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   2 & 3 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$, $\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   3 & 1 & 2  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$, $\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   3 & 2 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$. It is usually called the symmetric group $S_{3}$. Just out of curiosity I tried to find its commutator subgroup $\left[ {{S}_{3}},{{S}_{3}} \right]$. As a home assignment, I've already proven that the commutator subgroup is a normal subgroup, hence $\forall x\in {{S}_{3}}:x\left[ {{S}_{3}},{{S}_{3}} \right]=\left[ {{S}_{3}},{{S}_{3}} \right]x$. Except for the neutral element $\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$, I couldn't find a single permutation $p$ with the property: $\forall x\in {{S}_{3}}:xp=px$. For instance, $\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   1 & 3 & 2  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   2 & 1 & 3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   2 & 3 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\ne \left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   3 & 1 & 2  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   2 & 1 & 3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2 & 3  \\
   1 & 3 & 2  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The commutator subgroups does *not* consist of the elements $\sigma$ such that $x\sigma=\sigma x$ for all $x\in G$. That is the **center** of $G$. The commutator subgroup is the subgroup generated by all elements $c$ that make the equations $xy=yxc$ true, for all possible choices of $x,y\in G$. It is the smallest normal subgroup $N\triangleleft G$ such that $G/N$ is abelian. Note that $x[S_3,S_3]=[S_3,S_3]x$ is an equality of *sets*, not of elements.

Comment: These are good questions to ask yourself though when learning new definitions. Here, you are misunderstanding the meaning of $xN=Nx$. As Arturo mentioned, this is an equality of *sets*, not elements in those sets. In this case, $xN=Nx$ means any element of the form $xn$ with $n\in N$ can be written $n'x$ for some (possibly/usually) different $n'\in N$.

Comment: I was absolutely sure I had missed something. It turned out to be true. Thank you for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\forall x\in {{S}_{3}}:x\left[ {{S}_{3}},{{S}_{3}} \right]=\left[ {{S}_{3}},{{S}_{3}} \right]x$$

does not mean that $xp = px$ for $p \in \left[ {{S}_{3}},{{S}_{3}} \right]$. It means, for $p \in \left[ {{S}_{3}},{{S}_{3}} \right]$, we have $xp = qx$ for some $q \in \left[ {{S}_{3}},{{S}_{3}} \right]$, not necessarily $q = p$.